# Can you do something on a Google-Apps-Script fail?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to have an automatic 'back-up' plan if my Google Apps Script fails?  I'm thinking something along the lines of a python Try / Except.

For example, I am building a function to create a calendar event from a form (script is attached to the spreadsheet the form is linked to).  The script creates an event number for the new form submission (storing it in the spreadsheet) and then makes the calendar event.  If my function fails in making the event, there is a new event number in the spreadsheet, but no event in the calendar.

1. Does Google Scripts have a pre-built way to fail gracefully?
2. Or, is there a way to build an outer function that runs the original and has the graceful fail as (e.g.) the else of an if-then-else?

Comment: There's try/catch.  The base for Google Apps Script Javascript 1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps Script is based on Javascript, so you can use the [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) functionality.

If you are calling functions on your Apps Script back-end from your front-end you can also use the [`withFailureHandler`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withfailurehandlerfunction) to handle a failed execution.